# Popup parent is null

Tags: c#, wpf, frameworkelement

In my wpf application, I have some popups (menuContext and dialog) that haven't a parent. But when I open Snoop They have a visual Parent
[image: See this printscreen]

To get the parent I am using this code:

```
 public static DependencyObject GetParent(this DependencyObject element)
        {
            DependencyObject dependencyObject;
            try
            {
                dependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException )
            {
                dependencyObject = (DependencyObject) null;
            }
            if (dependencyObject == null)
            {
                var testec = element.GetName().Contains("Main");
                if (element is FrameworkElement frameworkElement2)
                    dependencyObject = frameworkElement2.Parent;
                if (element is FrameworkContentElement frameworkContentElement2)
                    dependencyObject = frameworkContentElement2.Parent; 
            }
            return dependencyObject;
        }
```

Why for some popups the parent is null? what can I add to this code to get parent =/= null ?
Thanks

I am looking to find the direct parent of popup. I need this to set automationId like this :
MainWindow....Parent.Popup.

Comment: What parent are you looking for and how is your `MessageBoxDialog` class implemented?

Comment: I am looking to find the direct parent of popup. I need this to set automationId like this :
MainWindow....Parent.Popup.

Comment: I don't know what Snoop returns.
You can view the Dynamic Visual Tree in a special Studio window after starting the project.
In this Window, all pop-up elements (Popup, ToolTip, ContextMenu, etc.) are rooted in their trees.
That is, they, in fact, are special small Windows, not visually associated with the Window from where they were called.